# Getting Angular UI grid working with Require JS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-grid

Hi could anyone help me correctly configure angular ui grid with requirejs.

So far I have the following and I'm able to create grids however I can't get the column resizing module to load along with ui.grid and tired several different approaches.

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "ui.grid": "../ui-grid.min.js"
    },
    "shim": {
        "ui.grid": {
         deps: ['angular']
        }
    }
});
```

For column resizing the module `'ui.grid.resizeColumns'` has to be added

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/204_column_resizing

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this config?

I wonder if you need to use camelCase instead.

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
        "uiGrid": "../ui-grid.min.js",
        "ui.grid.resizeColumns": "../ui-grid.min.js"
    },
    "shim": {
        "uiGrid": {
           deps: ['angular'],
           exports: 'uiGrid',
        },
        "ui.grid.resizeColumns": {
            deps: ['uiGrid'],
            exports: 'ui.grid.resizeColumns'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope does n't work. I've corrected the code and removed the 'exports' as `ui.grid` on it's own does n't work with that either.

The error I get with `ui.grid.resizeColumns` is:

`Controller 'uiGrid', required by directive 'uiGridresizeColumns' can't be found!`

The file contains multiple modules which is making it trickier to get it working. Also tried splitting the code into two files.

Comment: Can you post your html as well ?

Comment: I modified the config so that uiGrid is camelCase.